# Remove a specific value from a list (in R)

Tags: r

I am trying to remove a specific value from a data.frame within a list.

For example, in the below I would like to remove the value "85" from $V2

```
DF1 = list(V1= c(1, 5, 14, 23, 54), V2= c(9, 15, 85, 3, 42), V3= c(9, 7, 42, 87, 16))
```

I've tried

```
DF1$V2[-c(3)]
```

but that doesn't work and the alternate

```
DF1$V2[c(1,2,4,5)]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `data.frame` needs the same number of rows on each column so you can't really remove "85" from you dataset. What you can do is replace it with `NA` for example.

Comment: @DarrenTsai I meant to say list not data.frame apologies.

Comment: What doesn't work about `DF1$V2<-DF1$V2[-c(3)]`? It works for me now that it is a list object.

Comment: `DF1$V2 <- DF1$V2[-3]` should work

Comment: But note that strictly speaking `DF1` is a `list` and not a `data.frame`. Like already said, if it would be a `data.frame` then all the vector elements of it would need to have the same length.